# Copy messages from one Kafka topic to another using offsets/timestamps

Tags: apache-kafka

For some data processing , we need to reprocess all the messages between 2 timestamps
say between 1st Jan to 15th Jan.

to control upper bound we are planning to create a new topic that will have these messages so that once this task is complete , we can delete the topic too.
The new topic will have data from a particular offsets of source topic

partition 1 - from offset 100
partition 2 - from offset 2400...
and so on

What is the most suitable solution for this ? approx 10lacs messages fall in this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a consumer from the source topic.
2. Call `.assign` for the partitions you want to copy
3. Call `.seek` for each starting offset of those partitions. You can use `offsetsForTimes` method to get them for a specific timestamp; then you can pass those on to the seek method.
4. Create a Producer
5. Start a poll loop (one thread per partition, ideally,each thread with the reference of the created producer).
6. As polling, check the timestamp of the record

   - If record timestamp exceeds the date you're reading to, stop the poll loop / thread
   - Else, send that data via the producer to your output topic